# Invoking dependencies instructions from different file in sourceSet within gradle kts

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform

I keep my dependencies across many files to keep them organized.

I have created KMM project and there is `build.gradle.kts` file in my shared module.

Let's say there is a external file called `dependencies.gradle.kts` in my project with content:

```
apply(Dependencies.common)
dependencies {
    add("implementation", Coroutines.core)
}
```

I want `commonMain` from the shared module to use dependencies declared inside `A.gradle.kts`, how can I achieve it?

```
sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        // dependencies from dependencies.gradle.kts
    }
}
```

[Directory structure in project image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qkah.png)

Answer (score 1):

If `A.gradle.kts` is the build script for a specific module (I'll call it module A), you could just add a dependency on the module `implementation(project(":A"))`, even if that module only contains that build script and it's for sharing dependencies between modules perhaps (later on you could enrich this module A with shared utility or any other stuff)

If it isn't under a module, I'd create such a module, of course that module needs to satisfy the target set of the dependent KMM modules.

Comment: It would be an overkill in my solution to create module out of this single gradle script. I added an image showing the project structure and renamed files in the topic description to match the image. The thing is that the dependencies.gradle.kts is just a file in the same module.